# How to know in svn the last revision of each file or the last editor

Tags: svn

I'm working on a project which is under svn. One of the project members made a change to some files in a specific directory which I reverted. Now I ask myself: Did I replaced all the files he changed or are there some files which I missed? What is the svn command to tell for each file in a certain directory what is the last revision it was changed or who was its last editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html:

> With `--verbose` (`-v`), *svn list* shows the following fields for each item:
>
> - Revision number of the last commit
> - Author of the last commit
> - If locked, the letter “O” (see the preceding section on svn info for details).
> - Size (in bytes)
> - Date and time of the last commit